# MYSQL result not returning correctly

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, pdo

So I have a piece of code that will check if you have followed a user or not. And basically let you follow them if you haven't. So here it is

```
if($_SESSION['loggedIn'] == true){
    $result = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM followers WHERE follow_from = :username AND follow_to = :post_id");
    $result->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $result->bindParam(':post_id', $follower);
    $result->execute();
    $reprint = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
print_r($reprint);
if($reprint < 1){
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO followers (follow_from, follow_to) VALUES (:ff, :ft)");
    $stmt->bindValue(':ff', $follower, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':ft', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
}
else{
    echo 'Error';
    exit();
}
//Display follower
$stmt1 = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM followers WHERE follow_to = :username");
$stmt1->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt1->execute();
$likes = $stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($likes);
```

So when I run it once. I get the else statement echoed. My question is why does this happen? In the database I have no record, so I'd expect it to go in once. I get no errors at all. `loggedIn` is true. And variables are being passed through successfully. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Try `if(sizeof($reprint) < 1)`

Comment: It looks like `$reprint` will never be less than 1. You want to know the number of rows returned.

Comment: Have you tried to fetch the actual errors provided? Not just your home-made 'Error'? You could wrap your code into a try catch statement and catch the error message: catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

Comment: Yeah I have @Jonast92

Comment: It adds the record, but doesn't limit it to me one, which is what the code is supposed to do @AlbinGeorge

Comment: And I'd do that how? @JayBlanchard

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php @user302975

Comment: Still allows me to enter more than one row. So I'd assume its not working @JayBlanchard

Comment: Then it would seem that your logic is off or there is some code that you're not showing. How does this allow you to enter more than one row? There is no loop *that you're showing us*.

Comment: Well since this is a followers list, I'll check if `follow_from` and `follow_to` already exists. If it doesn't which is why I use `$reprint <1` to check if it doesn't and enter it. @JayBlanchard

Comment: That still doesn't make sense. Is there more code involved here that you're not showing?

Comment: Only my `GET` variable. A session variable. And code to display the result. All of which have nothing to do with the actual execution @JayBlanchard

Comment: `$reprint` will never be less than one in the code that you have above, so the succeeding error condition will always be echoed out. `$result->rowCount()` is the only function that will return the kind of number that you're looking for here...the number of rows returned from your first query. How did you test rowCount()?

Comment: I get `0` from `rowCount()` @JayBlanchard

Comment: Then you should be able to do `if($result->rowCount() == 0)` or `if($result->rowCount() < 1)`. Or you could assign the row count to `$reprint`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misusing the result you get from `fetchAll()`. It's an associative array, not a scalar value. It could, as you've probably guessed, be empty.

But, more significantly than that, your code has a potential race condition. What happens if two different sessions are trying to set this same `followers` row? (Admittedly, in a small system that is unlikely, but in a large system it might happen).

What you actually do is just the `INSERT` operation. If your `followers` row has a unique key on the `(follow_from,follow_to)` columns, then, if that row is already there you'll get a `'Duplicate entry'` error on the INSERT. Otherwise it will just happen. You can just ignore the `'Duplicate entry'` error, because all you want is for that row to make it into that table.

So your code would go like this:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT 
                         INTO followers (follow_from, follow_to)
                       VALUES (:ff, :ft)");
$stmt->bindValue(':ff', $follower, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':ft', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result = $stmt->execute();
if ($result) {
     /* this follow pair was successfully added */
} else {
     /* MySQL may return the error 'Duplicate entry' */
     if (false == stripos($stmt->errorCode,'Duplicate')){
        echo 'Something failed in the insert: ' . '$stmt->errorCode';
     }
     else {
         /* this follow pair was already in your table */
     }
}
```

Pro tip: Don't use `SELECT *` in software; it can mess up query optimization; it often sends more data than you need from the server to your program, and it makes your program less resilient if your change your table definitions.

Pro tip: If you must count rows matching a particular `WHERE` statement, use `COUNT()` rather than fetching the rows and counting them in the client. What if you get a million rows?

Comment: +1 for mentioning race condition. Just a small remark - PDOStatement::bindValue has a default data_type value of PDO::PARAM_STR anyways so there is no need to explicitly specify it

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to use count($reprint) other that a direct comparison. $reprint is an array, not a number

```
if(count($reprint) < 1)
{
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO followers (follow_from, follow_to) VALUES (:ff, :ft)");
    $stmt->bindValue(':ff', $follower, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':ft', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
}
else
{
    echo 'Error';
    exit();
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't limit it me to one record, so I'd assume it isn't checking that step...

Answer (score 1):

[PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

> PDOStatement::fetchAll — Returns an array containing all of the result set rows

If you check the size of the array then you would actually know if something happened.

Using proper error handling can tell you if something's failing deep down:

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

You will need to enable PDO error-displaying:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

If checking the size of the array doesn't do it and you get no errors then it's simply some logic error.

Most likely the logic error is that

```
$reprint = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

doesn't get executed (wrapping the error handling around that should tell you why), so

```
$reprint = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

isn't given a proper value, meaning you'll always hit the else statement.

**Edit**

Your original problem was that "So when I run it once. I get the else statement echoed. [...] In the database I have no record" but now you're saying "It adds the record, but doesn't limit it to me one".

Can you be more clear about the actual, current, problem?

Comment: Already using the try catch block like that, as I said to you in the comments....

Comment: Also worth mentioning that PDO does not throw exceptions by default/ That sould be enabled this way: $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Comment: When it checks for it I have none. So it should run. But when I run it again it keeps adding.